# When appending elements in the list in Python, using while loop, it returns only the result of the first iteration

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop, try-except, timeoutexception

Learning web scraping in Python using Selenium. I want to scrape the prices and names of the goods from Amazon and store them in a list. I'm doing it using while loop until it is impossible to click to the next page an thus it will throw TimeException error. When I debug I can clearly see that everything works fine, my lists get longer and longer but then when it breaks and I print the lists, I see that my program saved only the first loop iteration in there. Don't really understand what is going on there.  Here is my code:

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

# paste url that you want to scrape
url = "https://www.amazon.se/-/en/s?k=mirror+sticker&language=en_GB&crid=3LCT7C6GU8FUS&qid=1656847509&sprefix=mirror+sticker%2Caps%2C91&ref=sr_pg_1"
# this will open up new window with the url provided above
# put the path to the driver.exe file in the brackets
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
sleep(3)  # wait 3 seconds
driver.find_element(By.ID, "sp-cc-accept").click() # cookies

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


def get_text_store(web_elements_lst, storage_lst):  # text (names and prices) of webelements
    for element in web_elements_lst:
        if element.get_attribute("textContent") != "":
            storage_lst.append(element.get_attribute("textContent"))  # if not empty, append
        else:
            storage_lst.append("No data")  # if empty str


names_txt = [] # here I'll store str names
prices_txt = [] # here I store str prices
while True:
    try:
        web_elements_names = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,
                                                  "a-size-base-plus.a-color-base.a-text-normal")  # names (webelems)
        web_elements_prices = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "a-price-whole")  # prices (webelems)
        get_text_store(web_elements_names, names_txt)  # text from webelems names
        get_text_store(web_elements_prices, prices_txt)  # text from webelems prices
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Next']"))).click()  # go to the next page
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout Exception")
        break
print(names_txt)
print(prices_txt)```
````

Comment: Your function `get_text_store()` appends elems to a list, but it lacks a return statement; i.e. the updated list is never actually sent back to the caller. Suggested fix: add `return storage_lst` to the end of your function block (at same indent level as `for element in web_elements_lst`:. And then in the `while True:` loop, change `get_text_store(web_elements_names, names_txt)` into `names_txt = get_text_store(web_elements_names, names_txt)` and same for the next line (`prices_txt = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a sleep as shown below

```
while True:
    try:
        web_elements_names = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,
                                                  "a-size-base-plus.a-color-base.a-text-normal")  # names (webelems)
        web_elements_prices = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "a-price-whole")  # prices (webelems)
        get_text_store(web_elements_names, names_txt)  # text from webelems names
        get_text_store(web_elements_prices, prices_txt)  # text from webelems prices
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Next']"))).click()  # go to the next page
        sleep(5)
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout Exception")
        break
```